# QLabel embedding in QStatusBar using Qt Designer

Tags: qt, label, qt-creator, qt-designer, qstatusbar

Is there any solution to embed a QLabel in QStatusBar using Qt Designer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't believe so. It's fairly simple to add one programmatically, though.

If you're just wanting to show a message, you could use: `statusBar()->showMessage(tr("Message Here"));`, or alternatively if you really needed a QLabel on the status bar, you could do something along the lines of:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("Message");
statusBar()->addWidget(label);
```

`label` would become a child of `statusBar()`, and appear in the first empty spot from the bottom left (`addPermanentWidget(label)` would add it to the first empty spot from the bottom right). If you place `QLabel label` in the classes header (or other var name), you'd be able to access the variable directly later (removing the initial `QLabel` type from the first line, of course).

Comment: How to adapt the code to use a translatable `Message`?

Comment: @Sigur Any reason you're feeling like this would be significantly different from dealing with any other QLabel?

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to use `tr` with `QLabel` but no success. I don't know how to use `QLabel` with translable text.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible with Qt Designer. I resolve it by creating label a in Qt Designer and later in constructor of my `MainWindows` add this line:

```
Ui::"class name of my MainWindows"::"name of statusBar Object"->addWidget("Object Name of Label");
```

In my application, the class name of mainwindows is `MainWindowsForm`, the status bar is named `statusBar` and the label is named `informationLabel`. Then I have:

```
Ui::MainWindowsForm::statusBar->addWidget(informationLabel);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible even if you would manually edit UI file.

Comment: I think it's a defect in QtDesigner

Comment: Not a defect but a missing feature. Sadly QtDesigner is not meant for UIs, which have multi-level structure (this includes adding a QLabel to a QStatusbar etc.).